# Parameterized Jenkins Deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

I want to use parameterized deployment with jenkins. I added a parameter 
(e.g. DEPLOYMENT_URL) but when I tried using the parameter Under **Post-build Actions** tab with **Deploy war/ear to a container** plugin and **Tomcat7.x** container, in **Tomcat URL** the paramter couldn't be resolved.

I got **java.net.UnknownHostException: ${DEPLOYMENT_URL} / $DEPLOYMENT_URL**. I tried accessing the parameter in these ways http://${DEPLOYMENT_URL}, http://$DEPLOYMENT_URL but non of it worked.

And please, I also tried accessing the parameter without **http://** and the result was **invalid url syntax**

My jenkins version is **2.5** under **CentOS 7**. Please what could be the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pardon, ssh for what?

Comment: I believe the DEPLOYMENT_URL is url of some repo right? If so, you will need to add ssh key to your jenkins user in that

Comment: The DEPLOYMENT_URL is the deployment container ip-address:port. And if the ip address and the port are used directly in the Tomcat URL, jenkins deploy to the container without any problem. But when I used parameter in the Tomcat URL of jenkins, the parameter is not resolved. I tried using the paramter in other plugins and it's resolved. But for this plugin it is not.